# IWAB0014E Unexpected exception occurred

Tags: apache, web-services, soap

I am trying to create a simple soap web service application using eclipse and I encountered this error.

I am using Tomcat v7.0 server and eclipse Kepler. Can anyone please help me out with this exception ?

IWAB0014E Unexpected exception occurred.

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.creation.ui.extension.PreServiceDevelopCommand.execute(PreServiceDevelopCommand.java:143)
  at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.runCommand(CommandFragmentEngine.java:419)
  at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.visitTop(CommandFragmentEngine.java:359)
  at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.moveForwardToNextStop(CommandFragmentEngine.java:254)
  at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleCommandEngineManager$6.run(SimpleCommandEngineManager.java:294)
  at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:464)
  at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:372)
  at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:1028)
  at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleCommandEngineManager.runForwardToNextStop(SimpleCommandEngineManager.java:264)
  at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.runForwardToNextStop(WizardPageManager.java:91)
  at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.getNextPage(WizardPageManager.java:154)
  at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleWizardPage.getNextPage(SimpleWizardPage.java:136)
  at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.nextPressed(WizardDialog.java:908)
  at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:428)
  at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:628)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
  at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:826)
  at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:802)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$New.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:259)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:279)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:290)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
  at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:243)
  at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:224)
  at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
  at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:167)
  at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:499)
  at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
  at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:213)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:420)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:157)
  at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
  at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
  at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
  at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
  at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
  at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
  at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
  at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
  at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because of improper setup of Axis2.

Steps:

Download Axis2 : Link--> http://ws.apache.org/axis2/download.cgi
Point the Axis2 runtime dir in eclipse : Menu--> Windows--> Preference --> Web Services--> Axis2 Preferences

Answer (score 1):

Your code throws a [NullPointerException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) at

> PreServiceDevelopCommand.java:143

`NullPointerException` means that you wanted to use a reference which was not initialized. Most common scenario is that you want to use a member or call a method of an object which was not initialized using the `new` operator or a factory method. Check the file where the error occurs at line 143 and see what could be `null` there.

Official description from the docs:

> Thrown when an application attempts to use null in a case where an
>   object is required. These include:
>
> ```
> - Calling the instance method of a null object.
> - Accessing or modifying the field of a null object.
> - Taking the length of null as if it were an array.
> - Accessing or modifying the slots of null as if it were an array.
> - Throwing null as if it were a Throwable value.
> ```

Comment: I think the issue that the OP is having is that the NPE is being thrown by the webservice generation tools within eclipse.

Comment: Yes, it is quite possible that an illegal service implementation is specified (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=417117), but my notes were describing the possible causes in general.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to clean the pojo class for which you are trying to generate web service.

Clean the class and compile again.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the client which you have already created will solve the problem.